# Android ShowcaseView Text Color

Tags: android, text, colors, showcaseview

The default color for the subtext in the android showcaseview library found [here](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) is white.  I would like to make the subtext black.  I cannot find any documentation on how to change text color.  There is a guide on XDA Developers which says how to change text color but it seems to be outdated.  Anyone familiar with showcaseview?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and managed to change the text color by editing the color value the library itself from Eclipse. This assumes that you have imported the library in Eclipse and that it should be visible from the package explorer window.

Navigate to: [Library package] -> [res] -> [values] -> [styles.xml].

Now, change this:

```
  <style name="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
```

Into this:

```
   <style name="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
            <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
   </style>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this answer is rather late, but I was struggling with the same problem.

This link [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2419939&__utma=248941774.1246556969.1402388324.1402388324.1402388324.1&__utmb=248941774.1.10.1402388324&__utmc=248941774&__utmx=-&__utmz=248941774.1402388324.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=257655816) (especially the section titled Theming) helped me customise the ShowcaseView effectively, rather than to modify the library itself.

Perhaps this answer will help someone else that stumbles upon this post in the future like I just did.